# Webpack code splitting adds module twice

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

I use webpacks dynamic code splitting, which works quite well so far. But I have one module (`mC`) with a large dependency that is required from two other modules (`mA` & `mB`). With code splitting there are two bundles created both with the same content of `largeLib`. And for each of modules on of the bundles is loaded. I would expect that only one module is created and used by both `mA` and `mB`

```
 mA    mB
   \  / 
    \/ 
    mC
    |
  largeLib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an specific name to the import solves the problem for me:

```
 import(/* webpackChunkName: "handsOnTable" */ 'react-handsontable'),
```

Comment: That is indeed a quick & dirty way of doing it. This only solves the duplication of the single big component though. If you want to solve it for all components you would have to look into CommonsChunkPlugin. But that is a ton harder to configure properly.

Comment: Also the CommonsChunkPlugin will be removed in webpack4

Comment: Yes, the reason I'll be updating on day 2 it is released :D